# encryption key exchange algorithm

Tags: digital-communications

We have RSA algorithm for encryption key exchange for example for e-commerce.

If we consider the case of wireless telecommunications. Is it possible to implement an encryption key exchange algorithm (public key, private key) directly from the transmitted waveform, for example a chirp or an OFDM signal,...?

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of techniques termed **Physical Layer Security** or **PLS** where the fundamental properties of the channel enhance the security of communication.

The [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jehad-Hamamreh/publication/328520886_Classifications_and_Applications_of_Physical_Layer_Security_Techniques_for_Confidentiality_A_Comprehensive_Survey/links/5bd5a00492851c6b27937d65/Classifications-and-Applications-of-Physical-Layer-Security-Techniques-for-Confidentiality-A-Comprehensive-Survey.pdf)

> Hamamreh, J.M., Furqan, H.M., Arslan, H.: "Classifications and
> Applications of Physical Layer Security Techniques for
> Confidentiality: A Comprehensive Survey." *IEEE Communications Surveys
> Tutorials* 21(2), 1773–1828 (2019)

contains the following statement in its abstract:

> The basic idea of PLS is to exploit the characteristics of the
> wireless channel and its impairments including noise, fading,
> interference, dispersion, diversity, etc. in order to ensure the
> ability of the intended user to successfully perform data decoding
> while preventing eavesdroppers from doing so.